# Autogenerating routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

Hi all am looking to generate urls in the following form:

```
/admin/charity_upgrade_review/:id
```

where :id is the id of the CHARITY object ive clicked on and is served up ADMIN controller [url = (`/admin/charity_upgrades`)]

In my  view (before I click the link to give my desired url, served by admin#charity_upgrades) I have

```
  <% @charities.each do |charity| %>
    <%=link_to charity.name, admin_charity_upgrade_review_path(charity) %>
  <% end %>
```

my routes are as follows

```
   get 'admin/charity_upgrades'
   get 'admin/charity_upgrade_review'
  resources :charities
```

When I click on the link generated by link_to the url I get is

/admin/charity_upgrade_review.:id

How do I replace this dot with a / ?

All the best
D

Comment: could you run 'rake routes' on your project path, and post the output here please?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `:id` to the end and tell it which controller/action you want the route pointed to:

```
get 'admin/charity_upgrades/:id', to: 'admin#charity_upgrades', as: "admin_charity_upgrades"
get 'admin/charity_upgrade_review/:id', to: 'admin#charity_upgrade_review', as: "admin_charity_upgrade_review"
```

Two routes are created both going to the admin controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Helps you. Pass the object id along with the link and in routes side, change accordingly.

```
<% @charities.each do |charity| %>
    <%=link_to charity.name, "/admin/charity_upgrade_review/#{@charities.id}" %>
  <% end %>
```

In routes.rb side:

```
get 'admin/charity_upgrade_review/:id'       controller_name#action_name
```

Comment: It seems that this does not work, as you need to map the controller and action that you want in the routes.rb file, otherwise an error is generated. The answer by user1884067 is what is needed!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what is needed was to add

```
get 'admin/charity_upgrade_review/:id', to: 'admin#charity_upgrade_review', as: "admin_charity_upgrade_review"
```

to routes.rb and everything worked fine from there.